# How to remove non digits?

Tags: java

```
private String removeNonDigits(final String value) {         
   if(value == null || value.isEmpty()){
        return "";
   }
   return value.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", "");
}
```

Any better way to do this? Does StringUtils of Apache has a similar method?

Comment: You might want to keep a leading minus sign in your string :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just for fun I ran a benchmark:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
import com.google.common.base.Predicate;
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;
import com.google.common.primitives.Chars;

public final class Main {
    private static final String INPUT = "0a1b2c3d4e";
    private static final int REPS = 10000000;

    public static volatile String out;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.err.println(removeNonDigits1(INPUT));
        System.err.println(removeNonDigits2(INPUT));
        System.err.println(removeNonDigits3(INPUT));
        System.err.println(removeNonDigits4(INPUT));
        System.err.println(removeNonDigits5(INPUT));

        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < REPS; ++ i) {
            out = removeNonDigits1(INPUT);
        }
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < REPS; ++ i) {
            out = removeNonDigits2(INPUT);
        }
        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < REPS; ++ i) {
            out = removeNonDigits3(INPUT);
        }
        long t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < REPS; ++ i) {
            out = removeNonDigits4(INPUT);
        }
        long t4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < REPS; ++ i) {
            out = removeNonDigits5(INPUT);
        }
        long t5 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.err.printf("removeNonDigits1: %d\n", t1-t0);
        System.err.printf("removeNonDigits2: %d\n", t2-t1);
        System.err.printf("removeNonDigits3: %d\n", t3-t2);
        System.err.printf("removeNonDigits4: %d\n", t4-t3);
        System.err.printf("removeNonDigits5: %d\n", t5-t4);
    }

    private static final String PATTERN_SOURCE = "[^0-9]+";
    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(PATTERN_SOURCE);

    public static String removeNonDigits1(String input) {
        return input.replaceAll(PATTERN_SOURCE, "");
    }

    public static String removeNonDigits2(String input) {
        return PATTERN.matcher(input).replaceAll("");
    }

    public static String removeNonDigits3(String input) {
        char[] arr = input.toCharArray();
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++ i) {
            if (Character.isDigit(arr[i])) {
                arr[j++] = arr[i];
            }
        }
        return new String(arr, 0, j);
    }

    public static String removeNonDigits4(String input) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++ i) {
            char c = input.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                result.append(c);
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    public static String removeNonDigits5(String input) {
        List<Character> charList = Chars.asList(input.toCharArray());
        Predicate<Character> isDigit =
            new Predicate<Character>() {
                public boolean apply(Character input) {
                    return Character.isDigit(input);
                }
            };
        Iterable<Character> filteredList =
            Iterables.filter(charList, isDigit);
        return Joiner.on("").join(filteredList);
    }
}
```

And got these results:

```
removeNonDigits1: 74656
removeNonDigits2: 52235
removeNonDigits3: 4468
removeNonDigits4: 5250
removeNonDigits5: 29610
```

The amusing part is that `removeNonDigits5` (the Google Collections version) was supposed to be an example of a silly, overcomplicated and inefficent solution, yet it's twice as fast as the regex version.

**Update**:
Pre-compiling the regex increases the speed, but not as much as one might expect.

Re-using the `Matcher` gives another slight speedup, but probably not worth sacrificing thread-safety for.

Comment: Try initializing the StringBuilder with the initial length on removeNonDigits4.

Comment: I beleive nr 4 can be improved further by looping over the byte array instead of calling `getAt()` in the loop, moving the digits as encountered to the start of the array and creating the string from that.

Comment: @bruno, that doesn't help.  The default length is 16, longer than the input string in this example.  Maybe it would give a speedup if the input string was longer.

Comment: @rsp, I've replaced #3 with one that uses your suggestion

Comment: @finnw, I still get about 50% off, I have posted my version as answer.

Comment: When running benchmarks it's imperative to let the VM "warm up" or the code may never even get compiled.  The rule is to do several trials consisting of N iterations each, choosing N such that your trials last on the order of a second.  Report the actual time divided by iteration count to the console after each trial.  Then watch until the results stabilize -- they should get _very_ stable. Then run it again and see how you get a completely different stable result! When benchmarking ImmutableSet my habit was to run each benchmark 7 times (7 separate VM invocations) and take the median.

Comment: Also, you really have to test only one thing per VM invocation. Otherwise you'll get wildly different results depending on what order you try them in!

Answer (score 7):

Your method seems fine to me - what exactly is it you're looking for when you say "better"?  Your method is clear and understandable in its implementation, and will have reasonably good performance.

In particular, unless your application consists of calling this method constantly in a tight loop, I don't think you'd gain anything noticeable from trying to make it more performant.  Don't optimise prematurely; profile first and optimise the hotspots.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a method which is being called frequently, you *might* get a speedup from compiling the regex to a Pattern and reusing it each time:

```
private static final Pattern digits = Pattern.compile("[^0-9]");

private String removeNonDigits(final String value) {             
  if(value == null || value.isEmpty()){
    return "";
  }

  return digits.matcher(value).replaceAll("");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another version might be:

```
public static String removeNonDigits(final String value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
        char c = value.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(c))
            sb.append(c);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: `toCharArray()` makes a copy of the string, which will be more expensive than using `charAt()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getOnlyNumerics(String str)
{ 
    if (str == null)
    {
       return null;
    }    

    StringBuffer strBuff = new StringBuffer();    
    char c;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() ; i++)
    {     
         c = str.charAt(i);              
        if (Character.isDigit(c))
        {  
             strBuff.append(c);       
        }  
    }    

    return strBuff.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only a suggestion:
value.**trim()**.isEmpty()
or
(0==value.**trim()**.length())

If you have

```
   String value="     ";
```

- without the method trim()

  value == null || value.isEmpty()== false
- with the method trim()

  value == null || value.isEmpty()== true

The second is functionally more correct IMHO

Answer (score 0):

Adding my version of variant 4 to **finnw**'s fun above:

```
    public static String removeNonDigits4a(String input) {
        char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
        int l = chars.length;
        int m = 0;
        char c;
        for (int n = 0; n < l; ) {

            if (Character.isDigit(c = chars[n++])) {
                chars[m++] = c;
            }
        }
        return new String(chars, 0, m);
    }
```